# SelectedItem of a comboBox null

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm having a programming specific error that I cannot solve for the life of me.

Here is my code:

```
try 
{
    // Get the property depending on the value in the gaugeCounter. Ex. if the value of the gaugeCounter is 2, it gets the second gauge's properties
    DataProperty currentProp = manager.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Table, "Gauge" + manager.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Table, "gaugeCounter").Value);
    // Format: column|aggregation|the word "first/last" (used as a flag)|first/last column|the word "trellis" (used as a flag)|trellis column
    tableBox.SelectedItem = currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[0];
    columnBox.SelectedItem = currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[1].Replace("_", " ");

    aggregation.SelectedItem = currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[2];

    if (currentProp.Value.ToString().Contains("First") || currentProp.Value.ToString().Contains("Last"))
    {
        flColumn.Visible = true;
        flColumnLabel.Visible = true;    
        foreach (DataColumn tempcolumn in table.Columns)
        {
            if (tempcolumn.Properties.DataType.IsNumeric)
            {
                flColumn.Items.Add(tempcolumn);
            }

        }              

        flColumn.SelectedItem = currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " ");

        MessageBox.Show(columnBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " "));

        if (flColumn.SelectedItem == null)
                MessageBox.Show("N");
    }
    //if (currentProp.Value.ToString().Contains("trellis"))
    //{
    //    trellisBox.SelectedItem = currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[6];
    //}

    updateGauges();
}
```

The problem seems to be that `flColumn.SelectedItem` is always `null`, which breaks my program. I can't figure out why though, because `tableBox` and `columnBox`'s selectedItems are both not `null`, and I can confirm that the items in `flColumn` do exist. I printed every item inside `flColumn`, and it returned:

sepal length
sepal width
petal length
petal width

I also printed out `currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " ");`
which gives me

petal width

However, `flColumn.SelectedItem` is still null.
What would be causing the problem?

Thanks

Comment: ^^Quickly deleted my other comment; I realized that the problem remains. After I changed selectedIndex and then set the selectedItem right after, it completely ignores the fact that I set the selectedItem to currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " ");

Comment: flColumn looks like it contains DataColumns, but you are trying to select it with strings.

Comment: What type is flColumn?

Comment: It was populated, but I finally fixed it. Turns out that my hunch was correct; the strings had spaces at the beginning or at the end. I had to trim both the items in flColumn as well as currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " "). Resolved; this can be closed now.

Lars: the code I have now has Add(tempcolumn.Name.Trim()) now. I'm not sure when I forgot to add .Name to tempcolumn.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead test the value of `flColumn.SelectedIndex`?

```
        if (flColumn.SelectedIndex == -1)
             MessageBox.Show("N");
```

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't print N. At this point I think that the item being added into flColumn called "petal width" is somehow different than the "petal width" shown with currentProp.Value.ToString().Split('|')[3].Replace("_", " ");
I did run a comparison on them, and the two strings are apparently different, but I have no clue how as they look visually identical. I even tried .Trim() on my string; no difference.